# How to hold Parent-Child C# relationship with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, relationship

not sure if anyone can help me in this complex situation, hoping for good.
I am wondering if inheritance is the best way, maybe something else. I am clueless...

How should I set the relationship between the classes?

In the Database:

I have a Table called `tbl_contents` that has:

```
Int ContentId PK
Int ContentTypeId
Varchar ContentName
```

I have another table called `tbl_files` that has:

```
Int FileId PK
Varchar Path
```

I have made `FileId` as Foreign Key to `ContentId` so they actually share the PKs.

In the C# Code:

```
public class Content
{
    public enum ContentTypes
    {
        File = 1
    }     

    protected tbl_contents _content;

    public int ContentId
    {
        get
        {
            return _content.ContentId;
        }
    }

    public string ContentName
    {
        get
        {
            return _content.ContentName;
        }
    }

    public ContentTypes ContentType
    {
        get
        {
            return (ContentTypes)Enum.ToObject(typeof(ContentTypes), _content.ContentTypeId);
        }
    }
}
```

The File Class:

```
public class File
{    
    protected tbl_files _file;

    public int FileId
    {
        get
        {
            return _file.FileId;
        }
    }

    public string Path
    {
        get
        {
            return _file.Path;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

I have the Data Layer entities:

```
tbl_contents, tbl_files
```

and the two Business Layer classes:

```
Content, File
```

now, in order to address the Content class I can just select a LINQ query and get the tbl_contents entity.
 for example:

```
tbl_contents _dbContent = _dbContext.tbl_contents.Find(5)
```

now, I know from the ContentType that this is a File, and I want to get the Path from the file entity. I can get from `_dbContent.tbl_files.Path`, but I want it to be a part of a File class. after getting the entity from the db I can Construct the Content class: 
`Content content = new Content(_dbContent);`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using CodeFirst or DatabaseFirst model with EF?

If you want your [File] as a class property in [Content] class, simply add this in the Content class (virtual property):

```
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    public virtual File File { get; set; }
```

If you are following the conventions, the EF will find the relation. This works for 1-to-1 relations.
for 1-to-N relations add a virtual collection property.

`public virtual ICollection<File> Files`

and add a FK property in the File class (e.g.: `public int ContentId { get; set; }`)

Comment: I am using Database first with EF.
the DataLayer was mapped as you mentioned, I just want to know what is the best way to do it in the Business Layer

Comment: if you are using DatabaseFirst, then the model will be generated for you. No need to write it yourself i think... The business layer is as the business logic requires. No need to follow the Domain Model

Comment: Right, but that is just the layer that holds the entities.
If I have a Business Layer, how should I hold it?

Comment: Could be the same as the generated classes, unless you need something else. Not possible to say how to do your business layer with the info you supplied in the question. it depends how you are going to use it in the frontend. if no transformation is needed, just use the domainmodel classes. Add business logic only if domain classes are not approperiate, or you want to "flatten" some relations for easy displaying or something. There is no magic way to do it.

Comment: I have the Data Layer entities: 
tbl_contents, tbl_files 
and the two Business Layer classes: 
Content, File 
now, in order to address the Content class I can just select a LINQ query and get the tbl_contents entity. for example: 
tbl_contents _dbContent = _dbContext.tbk_contents.Find(5) 
now, I know from the ContentType that this is a File, and I want to get the Path from the file entity. 
I can get from _dbContent.tbl_files.Path, but I want it to be a part of a File class. 
after getting the entity from the db I can Construct the Content class: 
Content content = new Content(_dbContent);

Comment: Addition:

How should I hold the File class related to the Content class. 
(I cant construct it with: 
File file = new File(_dbContent.tbl_file); 
this is not a tbl_files entity, it's just a tbl_content entity with reference to tbl_files)

Comment: in the tbl_file, dont you have the reference to the tbl_content? if yes, why not to do it (call the constructor like so"File file = new File(_dbContent.tbl_file);" and in the constructor - navigate to the properties of the tbl_content? I am not sure i understand your issue